# Porting C# AES 256 decryption to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes

I'm trying to port this C# code to PHP:

```
private static string DecryptString(string content, string password)
{
    Rijndael aes;
    byte[] retVal = null;
    byte[] contentBytes;
    byte[] passwordBytes;
    byte[] ivBytes;

    try {
        //Get the content as byte[]
        contentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);

        //Create the password and initial vector bytes
        passwordBytes = new byte[32];
        ivBytes = new byte[16];

        Array.Copy(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password), passwordBytes, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password).Length);
        Array.Copy(passwordBytes, ivBytes, 16);

        //Create the cryptograpy object
        aes = Rijndael.Create();
        aes.Key = passwordBytes;
        aes.IV = ivBytes;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        string mode = aes.Mode.ToString();

        //Decrypt
        retVal = aes.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
    }
    catch {}

    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(retVal);
}
```

The `content` parameter is a 44 character long string, base 64 encoded, the `password` parameter is a 6 character long string.

This is the PHP code I put together:

```
$content = "[44 char base 64 encoded string]";
$password = "[6 char password]";

$padding = 32 - (strlen($password) % 32);
$password .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

$iv = substr($password, 0, 16);

$data = base64_decode($content);

$decrypted  = openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $iv);
```

The result of the C# code is a 10 character long number. The result from PHP is some 32 character long gibberish - I guess binary data.

Can anybody help me to fix that code, or has an idea what I can try?

Comment: Essentially the code is not secure. Keys should be created from a password with a key derivation function such as PBKDF2. IVs should be random for each encryption, never the password/key. The IV can be and generally are prepended to the encrypted data, they do not need to be secret.

Comment: @zaph I know - but I can't change the C# code, just need to port it to PHP :-)

Comment: Ah, so you are not concerned with security, I mistakenly thought security was the goal.

Comment: @zaph I am. But there is nothing I can do about it in this case. It is a service I'm consuming - created by others.

Comment: You chose to consume it. Either you choose to help make things more secure or less secure, that is the question. We really need to move toward more secure. Everyone has an excuse after the fact and they all come down to "did not care enough". It seems you chose "did not care".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by zaph in the comments this code is not considered safe and i advise against using it in a production environment. Quoting zaph's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362229/porting-c-sharp-aes-256-decryption-to-php/46373447#comment79685578_46362229):

> Essentially the code is not secure. Keys should be created from a password with a key derivation function such as PBKDF2. IVs should be random for each encryption, never the password/key. The IV can be and generally are prepended to the encrypted data, they do not need to be secret.

That being said, here is a PHP equivalent of your C# code:

```
function DecryptString($content, $password){
    $password = mb_convert_encoding($password, "utf-16le");
    $padding = 32 - (strlen($password) % 32);
    $password .= str_repeat("\0", $padding);
    $iv = substr($password, 0, 16);
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($content, "AES-256-CBC", $password, false, $iv);
    $decoded = mb_convert_encoding($decrypted, "utf-8", "utf-16le");
    return $decoded;
}
```

C# Unicode strings are Little Endian UTF-16 encoded. In order to decode them properly in PHP we'll have to use [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

PHP test:

```
$password = "012345";
$content = "EJWgZ/26wp+Cb5utbM1aMk8XfqPQide4dzjQzzzYfj8=";
echo DecryptString($content, $password);

//0123456789
```

C# test:

```
string password = "012345";
string content = "EJWgZ/26wp+Cb5utbM1aMk8XfqPQide4dzjQzzzYfj8=";
Console.WriteLine(so.DecryptString(content, password));

//0123456789
```

Some tips:

PHP's [`openssl_decrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) uses PKCS padding by default, and can handle base64 encoded data. We can take advantage of those features by setting the `options` parameter to `false`.

IVs should be random bytes. This is important because using a static IV makes your encryption vulnerable to attacks. You can create secure random IVs with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` for C#, and `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` for PHP.

Passwords should be as long and unpredictable as possible - 123456 is not a good password! Although you could use your password as a key (if it has the right size), it's best to use a key created with a KDF. You can use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` for C#, and `hash_pbkdf2` for PHP.

If you don't check the authenticity of the message, then your data could be altered, or your service could be vulnerable to padding oracle attacks. You can use a MAC to verify your message (`HMACSHA256` for C#, `hash_hmac` for PHP) or use an authenticated mode like GCM.

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks! You have no idea for how long I searched for a solution. About your security concerns - I'm merely a consumer of an existing service. So there is nothing I can change or do about it - but will pass it on to the creators of the service.